# How to handle error in express with class?

Tags: node.js, express, mern

I am trying to handle error with **class constructor** in a better way. I named my class **HttpError** that is written below, the problem is **HttpError** doesn't work properly.

**This is "app.js" file:**

```
const express = require('express');


const app = express();

const placesRoutes = require('./routes/placesRoutes');


app.use('/api/places',placesRoutes);

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json({message: 'the server is working.'});
    next();
});

app.use((error, req, res, next)=> {
    if(res.headerSent){
        return next(error);
    }
    res.status(error.code || 500);// This error shows when I am entering wrong pid
    res.json({message: 'Does not match any route'});
})


app.listen(5000);
```

**and this is placesRoutes.js:**

```
const express = require('express');

const HttpError = require('../models/httpError');

const router = express.Router();


const DUMMY_PLACE = [
    {
    id: '1',
    name: 'jahid',
    address: 'Rajoir, Rayenda, Sarankhola, Bagerhat',
    email: 'gahid@gmail.com',
    password: 'jahid5868'
    },
    {
    id: '2',
    name: 'saiful',
    address: 'Rajoir, Rayenda, Sarankhola, Bagerhat',
    email: 'gahid@gmail.com',
    password: 'jahid5868'
    },
    {
    id: '3',
    name: 'sadiqul',
    address: 'Rajoir, Rayenda, Sarankhola, Bagerhat',
    email: 'gkaid@gmail.com',
    password: 'jahid5868'
    },
    {
    id: '4',
    name: 'hasib',
    address: 'Rajoir, Rayenda, Sarankhola, Bagerhat',
    email: 'ahid@gmail.com',
    password: 'jahid5868'
    },
]
router.get('/:pid', (req, res, next) => {
    const sid = req.params.pid;
    const data = DUMMY_PLACE.find(p=> p.id === sid);
    if(!data){
       return next(new HttpError('Does not found uid', 404));
    }
    res.json({data});
});


module.exports = router;
```

**and this is "HttpError.js":**

```
class HttpError extends Error {
    constructor(message, statusCode) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }
};



module.exports = HttpError;
```

When I am entering **/api/places/:(wrong-pid)**. It doesn't show HttpError rather it's showing the error **500** from **bottom** of **app.js.**
I am new to express so please don't bother if my question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

With the above code an instance of `HttpError` gets passed to the error handling middleware, but you do not really use it there. You probably wanted to do something like:

```
app.use((error, req, res, next)=> {
    if(res.headerSent){
        return next(error);
    }
    if(error instanceof HttpError) {
      res.status(error.statusCode);
      res.json({message: error.message});
    } else {
      res.status(error.code || 500);
      res.json({message: 'Does not match any route'});
    }
})
```

Comment: That's not a good answer he needs to do a return if there is an error.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, can you elaborate? Also, did you just assume the user's gender? :)

Comment: if you don't return anything there is no magic and the function doesn't know if it's complete/incomplete. so it will just continue to run even if there is an error and on big code that's can be a probleme.

Comment: There is always an implicit return if you do not specify one ...  The problem could rather be that you do not call `next` inside of one of the middlewares. This would be a problem, as the request would hang, but as I use `res.json` in either case, that is not the problem here.

Comment: you right my mistake you can also do it that way. thank you.

Comment: but in general, you should add a return, because some times not in middleware, (and because he is a beginner), if not you get this famous problem. "In Express.js why does code after res.json() still execute?"

Comment: Depends, there is absolutely no point in using return inside `if/else` blocks when there's no more code after the blocks.

Comment: It's a bit of philosophy
 ;p. but you want to create scalable code.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you have many ways of handling Errors, I like to use try/catch blocks very simple to understand and very useful and clear. You're doing a block asking him to do something if it's getting an error it's passing it to the catch block.

For example:

```js
const validateUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body
    if (!email || !password) {
      throw new ErrorHandler(404, 'Missing required email and password fields')
    }
    const user = await  db.User.findOne({ where: { email }});
    if (!user) {
      throw new ErrorHandler(404, 'User with the specified email does not exists')
    }
    next()
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
}
```

so we try something (getting data checking it) if there is an error its passing to the catch block.

another simplest example:

```js
try {
      capture = await payPalClient.client().execute(request);
      captureID = capture.result;
      // console.log(captureID)
    } catch (err) {
      // 4. Handle any errors from the call
      return res.status(500).send({
        status: 500,
        error: err,
      });
    }
```

trying something (some paypal stuff from one of my code not important).
if I'm getting an error from it I return a response (500 with a message of error .)

you can check on google for error handling express try/catch